# PHP simple proxy

Tags: php, proxy, dns

I need a simple proxy PHP function/script that can download a file from a foreign domain, and also allow me to modify the data (as strings) before retransmit. Any ideas better than "readfile($url)" ??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

file_get_contents(), fopen(), http_get() or [curl](http://php.net/manual/function.curl-init.php) are methods and functions you probably want to take a look at. Depending on what you are downloading and how you want to change it you could use [XML Parser](http://php.net/manual/book.xml.php), regex or a simple str_replace().

Comment: +1, but I'd recommend DomXML  or simplexml, and xpath over the old expat library.  The expat library is compatible and efficient for reading old files... but that's about all it has going for it.

Answer (score 3):

[PHP Reverse Proxy with Apache](http://demo.loopip.com/integration_demo/search/php_reverse_proxy)

Answer (score 1):

[php.net/file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents)