# How to "Forward" a Request and get the Cookies/Form Data Submitted?

Tags: php, perl, curl, proxy

I want to forward the request EXACTLY as it is, except from my server (a proxy).
For example, if a user submits a request to http://google.com/, my server will send that request to google.com, and return to the user the response. It would be nice if there was support for SSL/HTTPS, but I can do without it. The proxy also needs to save the cookies and form data submitted.

Comment: What you need is a  proxy .... not sure if a pure PHP proxy would be ideal

Comment: Do you have a more specific question? This doesn't exactly fit the SO Q&A format, considering how broad the topic is and how little information we've been given

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP simple proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046549/php-simple-proxy)

Comment: For example, a user submits the following request to my server: POST /path/script.cgi HTTP/1.0
From: frog@jmarshall.com
User-Agent: HTTPTool/1.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 32

home=Cosby&favorite+flavor=flies My server will send that request to google.com, and output to the user the response. Perl might be better, if there's something like php://input in Perl.

Comment: I think I'll try something with php://input and fsocketopen. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I've had some success with [Plack::App::Proxy](https://metacpan.org/module/Plack%3a%3aApp%3a%3aProxy)

You could try something like this to get you started:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Plack::App::Proxy;
use Plack::Builder;

my $app = builder {

    mount '/' => builder {
        Plack::App::Proxy->new( remote => 'http://google.com:80/' )->to_app;
    };  

};

$app;
```

Save this as app.psgi and run it with:

```
plackup app.psgi
```

Your proxy will now be running on port 5000